# FindById retorna valores que no puedo controlar en un if Java Spring

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual necesito controlar que las entidades existan mediante el ID , cuando existen este funciona sin problemas,el inconveniente es cuando crmdeal y salesNote devuelven valores nulos , por algún motivo estos no son controlados en el IF el error que devuelve es el siguiente:

Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

```
    SalesNote salesNote = new SalesNote();
    salesNote = (salesNoteRepository.findById(crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdSalesNotes().longValue()).get());

    CrmDeal crmDeal = new CrmDeal();
    crmDeal = (crmDealRepository.findById(crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdCrmdeal().longValue()).get());


    //Condiciones de entrada 1: IdCrmdeal Valido , 2:IdSalesNotes Valido

    if (crmDeal.getIdCrmDeal()!= null && salesNote.getCrmDeal()!=null) {

        //3 Flag en true
        if (crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getFlag().equals("true")) {
            salesNote = (salesNoteRepository.findById(crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdSalesNotes().longValue()).get());
            salesNote.setCrmDeal(crmDealRepository.findById(crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdCrmdeal().longValue()).get());
            salesNoteRepository.save(salesNote);
            return new ResponseEntity("Se ha editado una cotizacion correctamente: " + crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdSalesNotes(), HttpStatus.OK);

        }else{
            return new ResponseEntity("Flag debe ser true : " + crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdSalesNotes(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity("Verifique ID de negocio e ID de nota de venta : " + crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdSalesNotes(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Se debe introducir un try catch por cada parametro y abortar cuando arroje una excepción**

```
SalesNote salesNote = new SalesNote();

                 try {
                     salesNote = (salesNoteRepository.findById(crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdSalesNotes().longValue()).get());     //IDSALESNOTES

                    } catch (NoSuchElementException exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                        return new ResponseEntity("Verifique  ID Nota Venta: " + crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdSalesNotes(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT); }

                 try{
                     salesNote.setCrmDeal(crmDealRepository.findById(crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdCrmdeal().longValue()).get()); //IDCRMDEAL

                 }catch   (NoSuchElementException exception){
                     exception.printStackTrace();
                     return new ResponseEntity("Verifique  ID Negocio: " + crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdSalesNotes(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT); }

    if (crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getFlag().equals("true")) {
                  salesNoteRepository.save(salesNote);
                  return new ResponseEntity("Se ha editado una nota de venta correctamente: " + crmSalesNotesInitDTO.getIdSalesNotes(), HttpStatus.OK);

        } else{

          return new ResponseEntity("Verifique FLAG: ", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
```